# Converting stochastic probabilities into target numbers

Tags: r, game-development, dice

Given the following stochastic transition matrix, how can I convert these probabilities to random number generator target numbers?

```
transmat <- structure(c(0.77, 0.561, 0.14, 0.187, 0.07, 0.063, 0, 0.063, 
            0.01, 0.125, 0.01, 0.001), dim = c(2L, 6L), 
            dimnames = list(c("0", "1"), c("0", "1", "2", "5", "8", "9")))
```

The aim is to output target numbers for a transition to occur in a simulation environment. This can be done manually as in the example below, which gives approximations of dice roll ranges for the sum of 3 fair six-sided dice for the first row of the transition matrix (see the probability distribution [here](https://anydice.com/program/2c626)); however, an algorithm to do this is needed.

In the provided example, state 0 will remain as state 0 with a roll of 3-12, but will transition to state 1 on a roll of 13-14, state 2 with a roll of 15-16, state 8 on a roll of 17, and state 9 on a roll of 18.

```
   0      1       2       5   8    9   
0 "3-12" "13-14" "15-16" "-" "17" "18"
```

Conceptually I am unsure of how to proceed. One thought was to (1) index the probabilities in the row and the range of random number generator results and (2) somehow compare the cumulative probability and the remaining probabilities with the probabilities of possible random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you'd like to generate simulations from the probabilities in your matrix "transmat".

Apart from the literal way of performing the dice-roll simulation you describe (i.e. just generate random dice rolls using `floor(runif(n=1,min=1,max=7))` and generate the next state using some kind of `if` statement),

You could use `sample` to generate realizations from the probabilities in "transmat" directly:

```
sample(x=as.numeric(colnames(transmat)),  
       size=10^4,
       replace=TRUE,
       prob=transmat[1,])
```

The key here is using the probabilities from transmat as the argument to `prob` in `sample`. A count of the simulated states using `table`:

```
   0    1    2    8    9 
7681 1413  713   98   95
```

shows this is a simulation of the transition probabilities in the first row of your transition matrix.

Comment: This is very interesting, but I'm not sure if it is exactly what I'm after, and it is likely completely my fault in not explaining the problem well. I want to effectively print the dice roll needed to make the transition, given a particular type of roll (such as the sum of 3 6-sided dice). Could I use the sample method to in some way to generate these values? It seems promising, but I am not sure.

Comment: You are right, that is a different problem altogether. But your probabilities don't match? e.g. 3-12 is about 74.1 not 77. So you are approximating the probabilities with dice rolls, in which case you could calculate the cumulative distribution function for the dice specified and take the closest match to the cumulative sum of transmat columns.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me some direction. Definitely yes in this case some level of approximation is happening with the dice rolls. Any chance you know of an example of using the CDF for a similar problem? Thank you very much for your interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use different colored dice (or just roll one at a time)? That would give more states, each with the same probability. For example, there are `6^3 = 216` states with three dice if they are ordered by color (or by throw order). For the first row of `transmat`, it could be:

```
c(
  "1,1,1 - 5,4,4" = 0.768518519,
  "5,4,5 - 6,3,5" = 0.143518519,
  "6,3,6 - 6,6,2" = 0.069444444,
  "      -      " = 0,
  "6,6,3 - 6,6,4" = 0.009259259,
  "6,6,5 - 6,6,6" = 0.009259259
)
#> 1,1,1 - 5,4,4 5,4,5 - 6,3,5 6,3,6 - 6,6,2      -        6,6,3 - 6,6,4 6,6,5 - 6,6,6 
#>  0.768518519   0.143518519   0.069444444   0.000000000   0.009259259   0.009259259
```

Each additional die/roll would increase the precision by a factor of 6.

If that's an option, I have some ideas about automating it.

Comment: Wow...I am very intrigued by this. Digit dice? Or maybe you're just presenting it in a way I haven't seen before. I mean its not something I've even considered but its interesting for sure.